# Overlap image onto another section while pushing content out of the way

Tags: html, css

Current: http://jsfiddle.net/nmd1abot/

Desired: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP5z7.jpg

Basic structure

```
Section
    Header
    Body
    Graphic
Section
    Header
    Body
```

I need help getting the graphic to overlap into the grey section while pushing the header of the second section down more.

Is there a solution that doesn't involve manually setting the padding of the second section?

It is likely that many other pages that I build will use this design, but the image size is not standardized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nmd1abot/2/

Simply add

```
margin-top: -50px; 
padding-top: 50px;
```

to your `.two`

So basically a negative margin-top will push `.two` up, but also it's inner content.
Than to pull back the content down the same amount of top-padding will do the job.

Comment: i think i need to type faster :D

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes hehehh beat you by 9sec :D

Comment: WOW. Thanks. My mistake was thinking about moving the image and not the secondary section. Now that I have my answer, I can start thinking about how to fit it into my site's architecture. But, I can do that on my own.

Comment: @Chris you're welcome! Yes, I think it should be now a relatively easy task for you! Happy coding!